# What is the most efficient way to implement this in parallel?

Tags: java, concurrency, parallel-processing, executorservice, fork-join

Consider a collection of 50,000 objects.
Each object as produces 10 doubles per iteration, via its doWork() method.

There is a continuous while loop which goes over each of the 50,000 objects and
calls doWork().
After this each of the 10 doubles created must be processed by calling process() on each of them.

The final step inside the while loop must sum the doubles produced in each iteration, and then log the output.

Does the design depend on the relative time it takes to complete doWork() and process()?

What is the fastest and most CPU efficient way of implementing this algorithm?

I imagine making use of multiple cores will help a lot...

Should I use ExecutorService or ForkJoin?

How should I split up the tasks?

```
List<A> listA = new ArrayList<>();
populateWith50k(listA); // has 50k objects after this line
List<Double> listB = new ArrayList<>();

while(true){

    // causes a side affect, hence a change of state that the remaining code
    // depends on, hence I don't think we can use java streams...
    changeState(); 

    // the below depends on the system state setup above
    for (int i=0;i<listA.size();i++){
        A a = listA.get(i);
        a.doWork();
        populateUsingA(a); // populates listB, each A creates 10 doubles
        for (int j=0;j<listB.size();j++){
            B b = listB.get(j);
            b.process();
        }
        sumAndThenLogValuesInListB(a);
        listB.clear();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should probably use a parallel Stream.

```
listA.parallelStream().flatMapToDouble(A::doWork).sum()
```

will give you the sum of one pass through the while loop. You'll need to change `doWork` to immediately output the ten doubles, or introduce another method which does it, or write a more complex lambda body that does it (I wouldn't recommend that, for readability).

Comment: There is a side affect in the changeState() method so I'm not sure that would work, I cannot refactor to make things more in the style of functional code due to the complexity, I simplified the example to make it easier to understand. Sorry I didn't emphasis the dependency on the side affect which causes a dependent state change on every cycle of the while loop.